# Horizontal Primary and Sub menu is not align center, why?

Tags: css, menu, center, submenu

I'm building simple site from Drupal but the primary and submenu are not aligned center as it should. I have tried many of CSS3 properties but none of them is working.

This is how it structured

```
<div class="nav">
     <ul>
       <li>Primary Menu 1</li>
       <li>Primary Menu 2</li>
          <ul>
            <li>Submenu 2.1</li>
            <li>Submenu 2.2</li>
          </ul>
       <li>Primary Menu 3</li>
       <li>Primary Menu 4</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

I want to display both of primary and submenu to be horizontal and align center with CSS3, how can I do that, please provide completely new CSS code for me please.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are looking like this :-

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
     <ul>
       <li>Primary Menu 1</li>
       <li>Primary Menu 2
          <ul>
            <li>Submenu 2.1</li>
            <li>Submenu 2.2</li>
            <li>Submenu 2.3</li>
            <li>Submenu 2.4</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Primary Menu 3</li>
       <li>Primary Menu 4</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav ul {
background:lightgrey;
}
.nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 5px;
  position:relative;
}
.nav ul li ul {
display:none;
padding:0 10px;
}
.nav ul li:hover ul {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:19px;
  right:0;
}
.nav ul li ul li {
  display:block;
  margin:5px 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/GkWGySTM)

Comment: Shailender, the sub menu is still vertical, I want it to be horizontal and aligned center, can you provide the new one css?

Comment: Pakinai please come here :- http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15567/front-end-developer

Comment: I have not enough requirement to talk in there.

Comment: By the way, can you adjusted the sub menu to be at the center?

Comment: you can easily set to define the position:left;

Comment: Okay, I have got it now. Thanks